# Importing in Node.js: error "Must use import to load ES Module"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to import `myArr` from **hello.js** into **index.js**. However I get an error of

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module
```

File **hello.js**

```
export let myArr = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey'];
```

File **index.js**

```
import { myArr } from './hello.js';
console.log(myArr);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What version of node.js?  If your file does not have a file extension `.mjs`, there is a [whole set of rules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) for what you have to do to get `import` and `export` to work in node.js.  When I experimented with it, I found it quite a pain.  I'm sure there will come a day when it's just built-in and easy to use, but node.js isn't there yet.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I ran your code without any problems. Check for two things:

1. Node.js version >= 14. It only works with the latest version of Node.js.
2. Make sure your `package.json` includes a line for `"type": "module"`. Without this line, Node.js assumes you want to use [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) modules rather than ESM.

Comment: My file is called .mjs then why should it demand the "type": "module" in packages.json, this change breaks other scripts :< I will have to do some hack where I add it just before my script runs and then removes it again ^^ not pretty..

Comment: I dunno what happened but I went to node 14 had to change to "type": "module" ran successfully, removed "type": "module" and now I can run it without it :D

Comment: Also remember to remove `node_modules` and re-do a `npm install`

Comment: I have both. Node is 14.17 and package.json has `"type": "module"`. I do not know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Leads to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension)

Comment: Also remember to remove the `--require|-r` flag, e.g. `node -r ./server`

Answer (score 84):

Use version 2:

```
npm install node-fetch@2
```

*node-fetch* from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with *require()*.

If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS). Critical bug fixes will continue to be published for v2.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the relation between the question and `node-fetch`?

Comment: This... doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy for me the error in the question comes up when trying to use `node-fetch@3` in typescript while debugging with `ts-node`. A web search brought me here, and I am guessing many others are seeing this

Comment: Not the answer to this question, but i'm guessing most people who ended up here, got to this problem because of that package. This actually solved the problem for now. Not sure how to deal with the import even though I'm using node 14.9

Comment: This seems unrelated to the question but it did fix the error for me!

Comment: this is so broken...

Answer (score 25):

I ran into a similar issue while building my [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) project.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/pradeep/Work/my_project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard/_index.mjs
```

Then I realized that I am on a ***different Node.js version than the one used to install packages in this project***.

I had two options:

1. Change Node.js version to the one required by this project and build again.
2. Stay on the Node.js version you have and remove the **node_modules** directory and **package-lock.json** file and do **npm install** again.

I chose the first approach and it worked for me.

Comment: if you haven't realized I would be still struggling. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you have Node.js version lower than 14, e.g., v12 - you must specify this flag:

```
node --experimental-modules your.mjs
```

Comment: In that order. Don't even think about doing this `node your.mjs --experimental-modules`

Answer (score 5):

I use nvm to install the latest stable version of Node.js.

To delete the *package-lock.json* file and the [*node_modules* folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder), run npm. I then `npm start` to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Rename *hello.js* to *hello.mjs*.

You are using [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) right now with the *.js* extension. To import [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) modules, you will have to change the extension of the file that you want to import to *.mjs* so it knows that it is an ES6 module.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Node.js does not currently support import and export natively yet. It is still experimental according to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules). I recommend you use [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) to compile your code and allow you to use import and export.

For example, you can install the **@babel/node** package and run your project using:

```
npx babel-node index.js
```

Here are the documentation for [@babel/node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html). Like the documentation state, this command is only meant for local development. In production, they recommend [a configuration like this](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server).

Comment: The flag isn't required since node 14

Comment: @AluanHaddad - Just for the sake of clarity, Node 14 is pretty new.  It just went "current" last month and won't be "active" until something like this October.  So, v14 is in the process of arriving.  People can go grab it if they want to, but the point of the period between current and active is to make sure it's stable and to give library authors time to adapt to it (if necessary).  And, the nodejs v14 doc says "Experimental support for ECMAScript modules is enabled by default. ".  So, you don't need the flag any more in V14, but it is still in the "experimental" stage.