# Error: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\node_modules\react-markdown\index.js require() of ES modules is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, markdown, strapi

Currently I'm using `"react": "17.0.2"` and I have installed `"react-markdown": "^7.0.1"` via `npm i react-markdown` I'm using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) to display my rich text that I'm fetching from my Strapi CMS. I have used the following code to display the content:

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

export default function name({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>
          {posts.Title}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ReactMarkdown source={posts.Content} escapeHtml={false} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/blogs");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

But when I run this it gives me the following error:

[image]

I'm using node `v14.17.0` and have tried adding `"type": "module"`.

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "passportlegacy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^2.0.1",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.1.16",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.16",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670459/nodejs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this by just pinning react-markdown to version 6.

With version 7 of react-markdown they moved to ESM only. There's a explanation of what that means [here](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c), but it seems Jest (version 27) still only has [*experimental* support](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/64de4d7361367fd711a231d25c37f3be89564264/docs/ECMAScriptModules.md) for pure ESM modules as of October 2021. I couldn't get it to work in my project, and version 6 of react-markdown works fine for now.

I think the next major version of Jest (version 28) might support ESM.

Comment: They moved to pure ESM prematurely. They could have built a hybrid package like everyone else is doing.

Comment: Yes. And I think Jest 28 is still blocked from supporting ESM by nodejs https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37648

Answer (score 4):

Node is currently treating your `.js` file as CommonJS. You need to tell Node to treat it as an ES module.

Try adding `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file.

You can place it anywhere at the top level. E.g.:

```json
{
  "name": "passportlegacy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

More information: [package.json and file extensions - Node.js 14.x LTS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_json_and_file_extensions)

Comment: Where exactly should I place "type": "module" in my package.json?

Comment: You can place it anywhere at the top level. I added an example in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this version

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.0"
  }
```

Then issue

```
npm install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue on a nextjs project and tried the above, but after things went messy I tried this aproach:

```
import react, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const ReactMarkdown = lazy(() => import('react-markdown'));
export const SampleApp = () =>  <ReactMarkdown>[your markdown]<ReactMarkdown>
```

You could wrap this in `<Suspense fallback='loading..'>...</`  to be completely save.